# Foreach loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem where i am getting the window size in  jquery then looping througbh three img elements to apply the width to the inline style on the fly.

The issue is that when the foreach loop is run i get this error in the console
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setAttribute'

I have put a breakpoint in the loop and applied setAttribute to *this* and it appears to work fine. I dont understand why when it loops through the array it is not treating each array item as an object but seems to be trying to access the array as an object.

```
var windowsize = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function() {

    windowsize = $(window).width();

    $( "#imgs img" ).each(function (){
        $( this ).setAttribute("style","width:"+windowsize+"px");

    });                                                                 
});
```

sorry if this isn't clear

any help will greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute) is a js method and not a jquery method.

You either need to use the raw js method on the DOM element directly or use the [jQuery version .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) of the method.

Both the below ways are the same, but personally using the native js feels better.

```
$( this ).attr("style","width:"+windowsize+"px");
this.setAttribute("style","width:"+windowsize+"px");
```

Comment: But if you do use the jQuery version, you could do away with the loop to make it shorter: `$("#imgs img").width(windowsize);`

Comment: Thanks very much, I actually didnt know I couldnt use raw js methods on jquery objects. that helped alot!

Answer (score 1):

`.setAttribute()` is a native Javascript method. As you're using jQuery, use `.attr()` instead:

```
$(this).attr("style", "width:" + windowsize + "px");
```

or:

```
$(this).css("width", windowsize + "px");
```

or even better:

```
$(this).width(windowsize);
```